# Comments on scalastyle:ignore

Tags: scala, scalastyle

When I tell scalastyle to ignore a line, I would like to put a comment in the code explaining to future developers why that line deserves exemption from the normal rules.

I can obviously put it in the previous line, like:

```
// might be called from java code
if (foo == null) {  // scalastyle:ignore
    ...
}
```

But ideally, I would like it in-line, like:

```
if (foo == null) { // scalastyle:ignore : Might be called from java code
    ...
}
```

The main reason for this doesn't really jump out with a simple example as above - it's more crucial in multi-line statements like

```
foo
  .bar // scalastyle:ignore
  .baz
```

Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: How about `/* might be called from java code */ // scalastyle:ignore`?

Comment: seems like a reasonable feature request to make over at https://github.com/scalastyle/scalastyle

Comment: ah, duh... thanks, Oleg, that's pretty simple and clean.